# How to install razor engine with nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, razorengine

The instructions on https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/3.9.3 say to  type in  Install-Package RazorEngine -Version 3.9.3 at the PM>

I  get the error below. What am I missing?
I'm using VS2015, Thanks

> PM> Install-Package RazorEngine -Version 3.9.3
>   Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'RazorEngine.3.9.3' with respect to project 'ConsoleApplication3', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
>   Install-Package : Package 'RazorEngine,3.9.3' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'C:\aDev2015\RazorEngine-master'. Please verify all 
>   your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package RazorEngine -Version 3.9.3
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

PM>

Comment: Do you have tried Matt Ward's suggestion and what's the result? If any problem, please feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the main nuget.org package source is enabled. If it is enabled then disable the source that is pointing to `C:\aDev2015\RazorEngine-master` or add  RazorEngine.3.9.3.nupkg file to that directory.

Comment: I added RazorEngine.3.9.3.nupkg file to that directory same result, thx

Comment: @user2077340 Please try disable all other package source, leave only nuget.org enabled to check whether this issue still existing.